# Converter valores em reais para dólar

Tags: javascript

Tenho algumas valores em string no seguinte formato?

```
1.599,90
```

Preciso que eles se tornem um valor em dólar, como o abaixo:

```
1599.90
```

Tentei converter em float, mas o valor obtido não esta correto:

```js
console.log(parseFloat("1.599,90"))
```

Já pesquisei bastante e converter valores em reais para dólar eu não consegui encontrar, exceto o contrario.

Comment: Ultimamente esta difícil pedir ajuda aqui, já que além de não ajudar, ainda desqualificam a duvida das pessoas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o resultado poder ser obtido em string, você pode construir uma função como essa:

```
function realToDolar(num){
    num = num.replace('.', '');
    num = num.replace(',', '.');
    return num
}
```

Ela formata o valor de entrada removendo o ponto do milhar e substitui a vírgula da casa decimal para um ponto. Basta executar a função:

```
var numeroReal = "1.599,90";
var numeroDolar = realToDolar(numeroReal); // retorna "1599.90"
```

Comment: Você precisa utilizar uma expressão regular, ou então o método `replace` só irá substituir a primeira instancia encontrada na string. Se o número for `'1.000.599,90'`, essa solução não irá funcionar.

Comment: Como isso seria feito com expressão regular?

Comment: @Otavio, ao invés de `num.replace('.', '')`, seria `num.replace(/\./g, '')`

Comment: Muito obrigado pessoal. Embora algumas pessoas tenham desqualificado minha dúvida, agradeço por vocês dois terem dedicado um tempinho pra me ajudar